# Sql convert data into one row from multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have a table

[image]

and I want to convert it into one row for each customer number something like this:

[image]

Can someone point me to the right place , example where I can do similar thing.

Comment: The key term you are looking for is 'pivot'.  I'm short on time now, but I can provide a solution later today if nobody beats me to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [PIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Something like the following query should help.

```
SELECT CustomerNumber, 
    CASE WHEN [1] > 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END [Sony],
    CASE WHEN [2] > 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END [LG],
    CASE WHEN [3] > 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END [Samsung]
FROM
(SELECT Product1, CustomerNumber
    FROM Table) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
    COUNT(Product1)
    FOR Product1 IN ([1], [2], [3])
) AS PivotTable;
```