# Case for existence of row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query which performs a left join on tblKite.id=tblColorKites=idKite

It returns:

```
id  kitename    color
1   Sword   blue
1   Sword   green
1   Sword   yellow



tblColor_Kites      
id  color   idKite
1   blue    1
2   green   1
3   yellow  1
```

What i want is

```
id  isBlue  isGreen isYellow    isBrown
1   TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    FALSE
```

I can do that by performing  case like so:

```
  case when (select id from tblKite left join tblColor_Kites on     
 tblKite.id=tblColorKites=idKite where tblKite.id='1' and tbl_color_kite.id='2') = 2 
 then   'True' else 'False' end as 'isGreen'
```

This works, however, i'd like to learn if there is a more efficient way.

Comment: You are looking  for [PIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22048102/sql-convert-data-into-one-row-from-multiple-columns/22048520#22048520) answer I posted earlier today.

Comment: how does it compare to my approach? Will there be a performance difference?

Comment: As long as there are only 3 colors your approach may be ok (I mean acceptable). What happens if there are more than 3? Then your approach will not be acceptable, as there will be a large number of JOINs, one for each color in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do as an alternative to all the cases is use Pivot, for example:

Demo Data:

```
create table #tblKite (id smallint, kitename varchar(10),  color varchar(10)) 
insert into #tblKite values (1,'Sword','blue') 
insert into #tblKite values (1,'Sword','green') 
insert into #tblKite values (1,'Sword','yellow')

create table #tblColor_Kites (id smallint,  color varchar(10),   idKite smallint) 
insert into #tblColor_Kites values (1   ,'blue',1) 
insert into #tblColor_Kites values (2   ,'green',1) 
insert into #tblColor_Kites values (3   ,'yellow',1)
```

Query using pivoting:

```
select id,IIF([blue] is not NULL,'True','False') as isBlue, 
IIF([red] is not null,'True','False') as isRed, 
IIF([yellow] is not null,'True','False') as isYellow, 
IIF([green] is not null,'True','False') as isGreen 
FROM
(select #tblKite.id,#tblKite.color,idKite 
    from #tblKite left join #tblColor_Kites ON  
    #tblKite.id = #tblColor_Kites.idKite) x 
     PIVOT (max(idKite) for color in ([blue],[red],[yellow],[Green])) p
```

This will give you the expected result, mostly Pivot will transpose the data as columns and you need to define the function to group the results, in your case max over idKite will return or idKite or Null for every color.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer in terms of my question -- really helped!